# Хранение HTML-шаблонов

Tags: шаблоны, html, knockoutjs

Пишу я значит web-приложение. В этом приложении шаблонизатор находится на стороне клиента. В этом приложении есть много однотипных таблиц, но они отображают разные данные.  Также эти таблицы генерируются автоматически. Например такой шаблон : `<div class = 'mtable' data-gid = '' data-agid='' data-bind='foreach:rows'>
      <div class = 'row' data-bind='foreach: $data'>
                <span data-bind='text:$data.id'></span>
      </div>
   </div>`

и такой шаблон : `<div class = 'mtable' data-gid = '' data-agid='' data-bind='foreach:rows'>
      <div class = 'row' data-bind='foreach: $data'>
                <span data-gid = '' data-bind='text:$data.id'></span> 
                <span data-bind='text:$data.name'></span>
      </div>
   </div>`

Как видно они различаются. Атрибуты data-gid, и data-agid генерируются динамически через javascript. Вопрос такой, где лучше всего хранить эти шаблоны :

1. На сервере. Тогда надо придумать хитрый способ установки этих data-gid и data-agid, и прочих атрибутов data- javascript-ом.
2. На клиенте в виде строк. Тогда генерация упрощается, так как шаблоны можно оформить в виде функций, которые получают параметры,которые генерируются динамически, например : `function getTableHtml(gid,agid) { return "<dic class = 'mtable' data-gid = " + gid + " ..."; }`
3. Ваши предложения

P.S В общем случая получается. Что у нас сначала должен быть сгенерирован шаблон. Затем этот шаблон добавляется в DOM. И на него уже вешается модель.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Йой!))

Ну, во первых, они все равно будет хранится на сервере, откуда передаваться на клиент. Вопрос - как.

Собственно путей у вас два, у вас может быть жесткий язык разметки шаблонов, который парсится и интерпретируется JS-скриптом на клиенте. Получили данные, разложили их и прогнали данные и шаблон через интерпретатор, который разложил бы это все в ХТМЛ. На данном пути я бы рекомендовал юзать [готовое](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=js-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), а не изобретать велосипед.

Либо у вас может быть набор "библиотек" (в контексте JS - набор объектов), из которых ядро выбирает ту, которая может обработать конкретно данный поток данных и передает данные в эту библиотеку. Данный метод имеет смысл юзать только, если у вас очень сложные и экзотические вариации представления данных.

Comment: Странно) и почему данном ответе так часто употребляется слово данные. Что мне кажется, что от этих данных скоро будет сводить данную челюсть) С учетом того. что данный экземпляр никаких даннон и даннисимо уже сто лет не употреблял))

Comment: Спасибо, я уже решил использовать второй способ, т.к после некоторых решений дизайнера, появились во многих местах "уникальные" способы представления данных.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/javascript_usage - пожалуй, единственное вменяемое решение шаблонов на клиенте